# For locally profinite groups $H\lhd G$, is there a spectral sequence $\newcommand\@[2]{{\rm Ext}_#1^{#2}(\pi_1,\pi_2)}H^p(G/H,\@Hq)\implies\@G{p+q}$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, spectral-sequences, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a locally profinite group and let $H$ be a closed normal subgroup. Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be two smooth complex representations of $G$. Is there always a spectral sequence as follows?
$$E_2^{p,q} = \operatorname H^p(G/H,\operatorname{Ext}_H^q(\pi_1,\pi_2)) \implies \operatorname{Ext}_G^{p+q}(\pi_1,\pi_2)$$
Here $\operatorname H^{\bullet}(G/H,\cdot) \simeq \operatorname{Ext}_{G/H}^{\bullet}(\mathbb C,\cdot)$ denotes the group cohomology in the context of smooth representations.

I did find a paper [On the Continuous (Co) Homology of Locally Profinite Groups and the Künneth Theorem](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1994.1028) by Hitta proving the existence of a Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence in the case $\pi_1 \simeq \mathbb C$ (Theorem 2 loc. cit.). But what about arbitrary smooth $\pi_1$?

Comment: I haven't checked carefully, but presumably you could  deduce it from the Grothendieck spectral sequence for the derived functor of a composition.

Comment: @DonuArapura I have considered doing so, writing $\mathrm{Hom}_G(\pi_1,\cdot)$ as the composition of $\mathrm{Hom}_H(\pi_1,\cdot)_{\infty}$, from $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ to $\mathrm{Rep}(G/H)$, and taking the $G/H$-invariants. Here the $G$-action on $\mathrm{Hom}_H$ is $g\cdot f(v) := gf(g^{-1}v)$ and the $\infty$ subscript means taking the smooth vectors under this action. However, it is not clear to me if the acyclicity condition holds.

Comment: Isn’t this what you need: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04473 ?

Comment: @JulienHauseux Thanks for the comment. I feel like this does not answer my question, but only deals with the case $\pi_1 = \mathbb C$ is trivial, so that the $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups are Galois cohomology (a priori smooth cohomology, but continuous works as well according to this paper). Well actually, Theorem 1.1 of this arxiv paper seems to have been already proved by Hitta in the paper which I cite in my question, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to prove the existence of such a spectral sequence, at least when $H$ is open in $G$. In order not to leave this question unanswered, let me write things down.

If $G$ is a locally profinite group, let $\mathcal R(G)$ denote the category of smooth representations of $G$. If $V$ is an abstract representation of $G$, I will write $V^{G-\mathrm{sm}}$ for the subspace of smooth vectors. Thus $V^{G-\mathrm{sm}}\in \mathcal R(G)$.

Let $(\pi_1,V) \in \mathcal R(G)$. The functor $\mathcal R(G) \to \mathcal R(G)$ mapping $(\pi_2,W)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}}$ is exact and preserves injectives, see for instance the theorem in the section III.1.15 of the book by Renard and Schwartz. Here, the $\mathrm{Hom}$ space consists of $\mathbb C$-linear morphisms $V\rightarrow W$, and the $G$-action is given by
$$gf: v \mapsto g\cdot f(g^{-1}\cdot v).$$
If we compose this functor with taking the $G$-invariants, we obtain the functor $\mathcal R(G) \to \mathrm{Ab}$ given by $(\pi_2,W) \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}_G(\pi_1,\pi_2)$. Thus, we deduce that
$$\mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\pi_1,\pi_2) = \mathrm H^i(G,\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}}).$$
Now, by the paper of Hitta which I refer to in my question, we have a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence computing the right-hand side.
$$E_2^{i,j} = \mathrm H^i(G/H,\mathrm H^j(H,\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}})) \implies \mathrm H^i(G,\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}})$$

Inside the $E_2^{i,j}$ term, one must be a litte bit careful. Namely, we want to replace $\mathrm H^j(H,\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}})$, seen as a representation of $H$ by restriction, with $\mathrm{Ext}_H^j(\pi_{1|H},\pi_{2|H}) \simeq \mathrm H^j(H,\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_{1|H},\pi_{2|H})^{H-\mathrm{sm}})$.

But $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1,\pi_2)^{G-\mathrm{sm}}_{|H}$ consists of all linear morphisms $f:V\to W$ such that there exists $K \subset G$ an open compact subgroup with $f(k\cdot) = k\cdot f(\cdot)$ for all $k \in K$, and equipped with the action of $H$ restricted from $G$.
And $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_{1|H},\pi_{2|H})^{H-\mathrm{sm}}$ consists of all linear morphisms $f:V\to W$ such that there exists $K' \subset H$ an open compact subgroup with $f(k'\cdot) = k'\cdot f(\cdot)$ for all $k' \in K'$, and equipped with the natural action of $H$.

Clearly the former is a subspace of the latter. If we assume that $H$ is open, then any $K'$ is also open compact in $G$, so that the two spaces are equal. Then, the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence above is the desired result.